# Detect malware that recreates files in /usr/bin with a backdoor

Tags: files, security, malware

I had VPS server and it has been hacked. and has been install a backdoor program always listen so prots and it operate whole / directory

Now I use inotifywait can see the virus program always delete and create the backdoor program with new names, about 2 second do once.

Now I want to know how can I see which program create and delete them? so I need record /usr/bin/ write and delete logs with operate program PID.

If I can know who is the "mother program", I totally can fox it.

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER: I am not a security expert, just have a keen interest in it. I highly recommend seeking out a professional service of a security auditor if the server is important/critical to you/your work.

inotify does not provide the information on process id, you can attempt to run `lsof | grep FILENAME` to see what process has the file open, but you will be lucky to catch the process in the act of writing it unless it keeps the files open for long periods of time.

However, your system is compromised. I would consider it untrusted as you have no good/reliable way of finding out what the malicious attack has done. As such you have no way to tell which bits of the system have been compromised - for example, they could have modified your `ls` binary to redownload the backdoor program even after you thought you had removed it. Properly and fully cleaning up a compromised system is not a simple task and is best done offline so you are not fighting the system while you do it.

Ideally you should shutdown compromised systems immediately to stop them doing any more damage than has already been done (to its own os, or as well as other systems). This can be hard if you rely on the system, but not doing so can lead to worse outcomes (entirely depends on what the system does).

The best way, in my opinion, to ensure the system is clean to to set it up again from scratch on another VPS, migrating the only the required data that you cannot otherwise reproduce (ideally from backups) after checking it for viruses/malicious code - if anything you migrate across has been compromised your new box could be as well.

It can be handy to keep around the old system offline for a bit so you can inspect it to try and find out how the attacker got in. Then use that information to improve the security of your system.

The best course of action depends on what the system is for/how critical it is. As such I would highly recommend getting a security auditor to look at the system and your setup to provide you with their best recommendations on what you can do.